# fields resetting after form submission

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I have created a page that lists down 10-12 fields of the contact object on the vf page. This is for record insertion. Now my requirement is that if I click on the button to insert a record and there is some kind of validation error, then the values that i put in the 10-12 fields should not wipe away. One of those fields is a text field which needs quite some data. If the insertion throws an error, the field is wiped and the user has to populate the fields again which is not what the user wants. Kindly help.

Comment: Follow form structure to get data back filled to fields after validation errors;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Try this [https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093viIAA](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093viIAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use reRender attribute in commandButton that is responsible for Contact insert. If any validation fails lets reRender the id of the  to show the error message. It will not clear the data in the fields used on the vf page. Also make sure that you are not clearing or reallocating memory to contact variable (used to show the fields on page) in insert method after validation statements executed.